# Custom plugin + permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How are they?
I have a problem with my own plugin. I have created a custom plugin with custom permalinks, but it don't work and I don't know why.

The url is:

**web.com/index.php?pagename=tus-stars&ficha=first-second**

I want to show url like this:

**web.com/tus-stars/first-second**

In other places of Wordpress the permalinks works perfectly, but when I try to do run in this page I have a lot of problems..

This is the code that I use for generate a custom permalink in this page:

http://pastebin.com/ghE7iBkh

What problem I have ?

One thing more. The "first" and "second" parameters only are a text string with one dash between both, not a number or other type.

I hope they can understand me :) My english is very bad !!

Thanks for all !!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your permalink structure to **`%pagename%/%ficha%`**.

Comment: This really could be a comment.

Comment: This comment could be the answer.